# Elastic Search when to add dynamic mappings

Tags: dynamic, elasticsearch, mapping

I've been having troubles with Elastic Search (ES) dynamic mappings. Seems like I'm in a catch-22.  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-dynamic-mapping.html

The main goal is to store **everything as a string** that comes into ES.

What I've tried:

1. In ES you can't create a dynamic mapping until the index has been
   created.  Okay, makes sense.
2. I can't create an empty index, so if
       the first item sent into the index is not a string, I can't
       re-assign it... I won't know what type of object with be the first
       item in the index, it could be any type, due to how the the app accepts a variety of objects/events.

So if I can't create the mapping ahead of time, and I can't insert an empty index to create the mapping, and I can't change the mapping after the fact, how do I deal with the first item if its NOT a string???

Here's what I'm currently doing (using the Javascript Client).

```
createESIndex = function (esClient){
    esClient.index({
        index: 'timeline-2015-11-21',
        type: 'event',
        body: event
    },function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            logger.log(logger.SEVERITY.ERROR, 'acceptEvent elasticsearch create failed with: '+ error + " req:" + JSON.stringify(event));
            console.log(logger.SEVERITY.ERROR, 'acceptEvent elasticsearch create failed with: '+ error + " req:" + JSON.stringify(event));
            res.status(500).send('Error saving document');
        } else {
            res.status(200).send('Accepted');
        }
    });
}

esClientLookup.getClient( function(esClient) {

    esClient.indices.putTemplate({
        name: "timeline-mapping-template",
        body:{
            "template": "timeline-*",
            "mappings": {
                "event": {
                    "dynamic_templates": [
                        { "timestamp-only": {
                              "match":              "@timestamp",
                              "match_mapping_type": "date",
                              "mapping": {
                                  "type":           "date",
                              }
                        }},
                        { "all-others": {
                              "match":              "*",
                              "match_mapping_type": "string",
                              "mapping": {
                                  "type":           "string",
                              }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }).then(function(res){
        console.log("put template response: " + JSON.stringify(res));
        createESIndex(esClient);

    }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).send('Error saving document');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you share the current mapping you're using now?

Comment: There is no mapping, that's what I'm trying to do. Create my own custom one, where everything is a string.  My question is when to create the dynamic mapping, since I can't until after its created, and you can't change an existing mapping in ES from what I've read, you have to reindex.

Answer (score 2):

[Index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to the rescue !! That's exactly what you need, the idea is to create a template of your index and as soon as you wish to store a document in that index, ES will create it for you with the mapping you gave (even dynamic ones)

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/my_template -d '{
  "template": "index_name_*",
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "strings": {
            "match": "*",
            "match_mapping_type": "*",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "string"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "properties": {}
    }
  }
}'
```

Then when you index anything in an index whose name matches `index_name_*`, the index will be created with the dynamic mapping above.

For instance:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/index_name_1/type_name/1 -d '{
  "one": 1,
  "two": "two", 
  "three": true
}'
```

That will create a new index called `index_name_1` with a mapping type for `type_name` where all properties are `string`. You can verify that with

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/index_name_1/_mapping/type_name
```

Response:

```
{
  "index_name_1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "type_name" : {
        "dynamic_templates" : [ {
          "strings" : {
            "mapping" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "match" : "*",
            "match_mapping_type" : "*"
          }
        } ],
        "properties" : {
          "one" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "three" : {
            "type" : "string"
          },
          "two" : {
            "type" : "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if you're willing to do this via the Javascript API, you can use the [`indices.putTemplate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-puttemplate) call.

Comment: Thanks @Val  I am using the JS API, but can't figure out how to apply the template when creating the index using .create().  There's no mention of how to apply the template param in the documentation... https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-indices-create

Comment: Have you seen my last sentence in my answer ;)

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing... I updated the post to show my code.  Any tips?  I'm stuck :/  I can see that the template exists using a curl  _template, but it doesn't apply the template to my records for whatever reason.  No errors either.

Comment: Oh I know... you should not create the index explicitly, just try to index a document in the `timeline-2015-11-21` index and ES will create the index for you. So you should use the [`index`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#api-index) call instead of the `indices.create` one.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either.  I still get type:long for "number_try" in ES using the following curl:  
curl -k --request POST --header 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{ "number_try" : 123, "description" : "your description goes here", "text" : "Your text goes here. Can be used instead of description property", "severity_type" : "error" }' 'myuri'

Comment: It seems that your dynamic template will only match string fields, know that `"match_mapping_type": "string",` will only match `string` fields in your JSON, not `long` fields. Whereas in the dynamic template of my mapping I had `"match_mapping_type": "*"`. See the difference? Can you show the mapping of your index after it's been created?

Comment: I noticed this and it works if I explicitly choose the match_mapping_type = "long", but the wildcard gives me a mapping error: 
nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [number_try]].  It doesn't seem clean to have to create 1 per core type...
I have also tried an array of types (match_mapping_type: ["long","float", etc], but that doesn't convert all of them.

Comment: Weird as I have `"match_mapping_type": "*".` and that works fine. /thinking

Answer (score 0):

```
export const user = {
  email: {
    type: 'text',
  },
};
export const activity = {
  date: {
    type: 'text',
  },
};
export const common = {
  name: {
    type: 'text',
  },
};
```

```
import { Client } from '@elastic/elasticsearch';
import { user } from './user';
import { activity } from './activity';
import { common } from './common';

export class UserDataFactory {
  private schema = {
    ...user,
    ...activity,
    ...common,
    relation_type: {
      type: 'join',
      eager_global_ordinals: true,
      relations: {
        parent: ['activity'],
      },
    },
  };
  constructor(private client: Client) {
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, UserDataFactory.prototype);
  }
  async create() {
    const settings = {
      settings: {
        analysis: {
          normalizer: {
            useLowercase: {
              filter: ['lowercase'],
            },
          },
        },
      },
      mappings: {
        properties: this.schema,
      },
    };

    const { body } = await this.client.indices.exists({
      index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory,
    });

    await Promise.all([
      await (async (client) => {
        await new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
          if (!body) {
            await client.indices.create({
              index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory,
            });
          }
          resolve({ body });
        });
      })(this.client),
    ]);

    await this.client.indices.close({ index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory });

    await this.client.indices.putSettings({
      index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory,
      body: settings,
    });

    await this.client.indices.open({
      index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory,
    });

    await this.client.indices.putMapping({
      index: ElasticIndex.UserDataFactory,
      body: {
        dynamic: 'strict',
        properties: {
          ...this.schema,
        },
      },
    });
  }
}
```

wrapper.ts

```
class ElasticWrapper {
  private _client: Client = new Client({
    node: process.env.elasticsearch_node,
    auth: {
      username: 'elastic',
      password: process.env.elasticsearch_password || 'changeme',
    },
    ssl: {
      ca: process.env.elasticsearch_certificate,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });
  get client() {
    return this._client;
  }
}

export const elasticWrapper = new ElasticWrapper();
```

index.ts

```
new UserDataFactory(elasticWrapper.client).create();
```